# Checking for adjacency in Python commits a miscalculation

Tags: python, algorithm

I am working on this leetcode problem [605. Can Place Flowers](https://leetcode.com/problems/can-place-flowers/). I am given a list like `flowerbed = [1,0,0,0,1]` and an integer like `n = 1`. The rule is that, given an integer array `flowerbed` containing `0`'s and `1`'s, where `0` means empty and `1` means not empty, and an integer `n`, return if `n` new flowers can be planted in the flowerbed without violating the no-adjacent-flowers rule.

**Example 1:**

```
Input: flowerbed = [1,0,0,0,1], n = 1
Output: true
```

**Example 2:**

```
Input: flowerbed = [1,0,0,0,1], n = 2
Output: false
```

This is my code. I'm starting a for loop from index 1 to `len(flowerbed)-2` and I am checking if the current value, the value before me and the value after me are all 0 and if so, I'm incrementing `counter` by 1. At the end, I'm returning a bool by comparing `counter` with `n`.

```
class Solution:
    def canPlaceFlowers(self, flowerbed: List[int], n: int) -> bool:
        counter = 0
        
        for i in range(1, len(flowerbed)-2):
            if flowerbed[i] == 0 and flowerbed[i-1] == 0 and flowerbed[i+1] == 0:
                counter += 1
            
        return counter == n
```

However, for this test case, its telling me that its not checking out. I don't understand why. There are 2 valid spots for a flower on the flower bed.

```
Input:    [1,0,0,0,0,1]
          n = 2
Output:   true
Expected: false
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should also update your flowerbed list in the loop:

```
if flowerbed[i] == 0 and flowerbed[i-1] == 0 and flowerbed[i+1] == 0:
    counter += 1
    flowerbed[i]=1
```

In this way placed seeds are also considered when trying to plant new seeds. Also, I would consider using the `staticmethod` decorator above `canPlaceFlowers`.